# Windows explorer "not responding" with right-click in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

I am finding that my Windows Explorer is "Not Responding" whenever I attempt to right-click either a drive or any folder in any directory in Windows 8. I have to restart the windows explorer process just to get it functional again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to disable 3rd party shellextension until you find the extension which causes the hangs.

[image]